# JAXB XML Unmarshalling creates xml classes's fields as well

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

I have an  xml and and at that XML I have too many child fields such like   . From the documentation that I read, I see that JAXB auto generated xml to pojo classes but there is a remark there , JAXB can create fields as well ? I meant do i have to create Employee class and its methods such like String job, String id myself or JAXB will create it themselves ? If my question is not clear, I can provide sample codes.

Cheers
Alper

```
        <code>
           <Employee>
             <id>121</id>
             <name>Alper</name>
           </Employee>
        </code>
```

Do I have to create String id; String name; as well ?

Comment: What is your target class?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. To create necessary Java classes (e.g. Employee) manually
2. To use XML schema to generate classes

But XML sample itself is not enough surely.

More information here: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

you can generate POJO or java class from JAXB in eclipse, command line or  maven.

you can file below several tutorials to learn this:

create POJO Class from XSD in Eclipse [here](http://www.javawebtutor.com/articles/jaxb/jaxb_java_class_from_xsd.html)

create POJO class from XSD using command line [here](http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java/jaxb/generate-java-class-from-xml-schema-using-jaxb-xjc-command/)

create POJO Class from XSD using XJC Maven Plugin [here](http://www.journaldev.com/1312/how-to-generate-java-classes-from-xsd-using-xjc-maven-plugin)

Comment: it means there is no way to create XML to POJO without creating fields Mayank. So I should try it with  XJC Maven Plugin from XSD to POJO. Is that correct?

Comment: as per my knowledge you need to create create fields.